# Контекстная лемматизация Python

Tags: python, nlp

Есть ли что-то для контекстной лемматизации целого предложения на русском языке, а не просто лемматизации списка слов? На английском это позволяют pyswd и spacy, но на русском они не работают.

```
>>> from pywsd.utils import lemmatize_sentence
Warming up PyWSD (takes ~10 secs)... took 9.307677984237671 secs.

>>> text = "Mary leaves the room"
>>> lemmatize_sentence(text)
['mary', 'leave', 'the', 'room']

>>> text = 'Dew drops fall from the leaves'
>>> lemmatize_sentence(text)
['dew', 'drop', 'fall', 'from', 'the', 'leaf']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Установка контекстного лемматизатора

```
pip install pymystem3
```

Использование

```
from pymystem3 import Mystem
m = Mystem()
def lemmatize_sentence(text):
    lemmas = m.lemmatize(text)
    return "".join(lemmas).strip()
```

Comment: Версия с pypi (2.18.4) не работает под Windows. Еще неплохо бы увидеть результат, который вы получили в итоге (по сравнению, например, с тем что в соседнем ответе).

Answer (score 3):

Для этой задачи можно воспользоваться морфологическим анализатором [pymorphy2](https://pymorphy2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/index.html). Создадим функцию `lemmatize`, которая на вход принимает предложение и возвращает список слов:

```
import pymorphy2
morph = pymorphy2.MorphAnalyzer()

text = "Съешь еще этих мягких французских булок да выпей чаю"

def lemmatize(text):
    words = text.split() # разбиваем текст на слова
    res = list()
    for word in words:
        p = morph.parse(word)[0]
        res.append(p.normal_form)

    return res

print(lemmatize(text))
['съесть', 'ещё', 'этот', 'мягкий', 'французский', 'булка', 'да', 'выпить', 'чай']
```

Comment: Это лемматизация списка слов, а не предложения. Она не учитывает контекст.